# EF 6 Reverse Engineer Code First with MYSQL - hangs VS2012

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to do a EF6 reverse engineer code first from a MySql database.  Visual Studio hangs dead.  I right-click on the project, Entity Framework, Reverse Engineer Code First, select the mysql database provider, test the connection, and then hangs spectacularly.  I have to kill the Visual Studio.

Has anyone got this to work with MySQL?  Note that I am able to successfully 'Test' the connection when I set up the database link, so it IS talking to my MySQL server because I see all my databases on the server.

I also removed the first line from file
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude

Per other posts on StackOverFlow.  No change.

This what I have installed:

```
EF Power Tools Beta 4 in VS
MySQL for Visual Studio 1.1.3 in Windows and VS
MySQL Connector .Net 6.8.3 in Windows
```

In the solution, I've NuGet-ed the following packages:

```
EF 6.0.2
MySql.Data
MySQL.Web
MySQL.data.entity.EF6
```

I'd appreciate any advice on how/if this can be done.

Thanks!
Corey.